# How to fix 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError:'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, model-view-controller, controller

I'm participating on this event called Semana OmniStack 9.0, on which we are currently developing the backend of an app on NodeJS with MVC and MongoDB, so in one of my controllers there is this error popping up 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Spot is not defined' which I tried to solve, but with no luck.

I already checked and compared my code with the Lecturer's, I think that I'm messing up with something on the async await side of JS, which I never have coded before.

This is my SpotController:

```
const spot = require('../models/Spot');

module.exports = {
    async store(req, res) {
        const { filename } = req.file;
        const { company, techs, price } = req.body;
        const { user_id } = req.headers;

        const spot = await Spot.create({
            user: user_id,
            thumbnail: filename,
            company,
            techs: techs.split(',').map(tech => tech.trim()),
            price
        });

        return res.json(spot);
    }
};
```

And this is the Spot model for the DB (which is MongoDB):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const SpotSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    thumbnail: String,
    company: String,
    price: Number,
    techs: [String],
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Spot', SpotSchema);
```

And after I run Insomnia (it's a program similar to Postman), the app crashes and throw this error:

```
(node:13956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Spot is not defined
    at store (C:\Users\sadkevin\Desktop\Programs\Rocketseat\SemanaOmnistack9\backend\src\controllers\SpotController.js:9:22)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\sadkevin\Desktop\Programs\Rocketseat\SemanaOmnistack9\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\sadkevin\Desktop\Programs\Rocketseat\SemanaOmnistack9\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sadkevin\Desktop\Programs\Rocketseat\SemanaOmnistack9\backend\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:53:37)
    at runCallback (timers.js:706:11)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
(node:13956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13956) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

After I sent the data with Imsonia it should return me a JSON file, any ideas guys?

Comment: My guess is that `const spot = require('../models/Spot');` is supposed to be `const Spot = require('../models/Spot');`? The error seems to be caused by `await Spot.create` where node doesn't know what `Spot` is.

Comment: Well I mistyped the Spot on the start of the controller them, thx and how do I mark your answer as the correct one? The option is not showing up here.

Comment: You can't mark comments; this question will be closed as typo so no need to mark anything :) you can also delete it yourself.